# How to read output of PHP Neural network

Tags: php, neural-network

I am using a PHP neural network from https://github.com/infostreams/neural-network/blob/master/example.php. This is my test data:

```
$n->addTestData( array('3','2'), array('a', 'b', 'c', 's'));
$n->addTestData( array('4','7'), array('m', 'l', 'g', 't'));
```

This is the output I am getting:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  float(-0.0030371278614825)
  [1]=>
  float(0.00074163516365296)
  [2]=>
  float(-0.0039751827109839)
  [3]=>
  float(0.00049371361222204)
}
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  float(0.00050773033843126)
  [1]=>
  float(0.0042996095442468)
  [2]=>
  float(-0.00080488821890052)
  [3]=>
  float(0.00068720478983485)
}
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  float(-0.0030371278614825)
  [1]=>
  float(0.00074163516365296)
  [2]=>
  float(-0.0039751827109839)
  [3]=>
  float(0.00049371361222204)
}
```

Can anyone tell how to read this output and what each of these values mean?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can input strings as input to the neural network. You should normalize your input data in a given range, e.g.:

```
3 -> 3 / 10 = 0.3
7 -> 7 / 10 = 0.7
```

Your outputs should also be normalised, you can do this via one-hot encoding:

```
A = [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
B = [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
Z = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1];
```

To be fair, the github repo you linked seems fairly outdated to me. Is it really necessary you need to perfrom the neural network operations in PHP for your website? You could also compute neural networks with a Javascript neural network library, e.g. [Neataptic](https://github.com/wagenaartje/neataptic).